# Hiding View in Fragment on Scroll of Other View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using Navigation drawer activity in content_main there is one linear layout which will be inflate with fragment.

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="net.techdesire.khabargujarat.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="fragment.HomeFragment">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_heightPercent="40%"/>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_heightPercent="60%"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewpager">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="@string/about_khijadiya"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/about"
                android:text="@string/dummy"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

I have large content in textview named about. I want to make it scrollable,like in image.First scroll relativelayout to full screen and if content of about is still overflow then make only about textview scrollable. When scroll reach to top and if user swipe down from there then re-display viewpager.

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. Could you try to explain another way?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your requirement is collapsing the view while scrolling.

> So you can use
>   "android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout".

It is implemented in material design.

You can refer this link:
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: Yes it is something like that but not exactly as it is. I didn't want to do manipulate toolbar and other things. can i make it with only change in one xml file?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on your perspective.